# Website text randomly becoming incredibly small

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts, visual-glitch

I've been experiencing a problem where sometimes, completely randomly, my website text becomes extremely small. This only happens on Firefox on Mac, as far as I can tell. It looks like this:

[image: The appearance]

When I check Firebug, I notice that there's a `font-size: 1px` set on the body, which explains the problem (the website is based off `em`, which follows the body font size). The problem is, I never set `font-size: 1px` anywhere inside my code. It says `font-size: 1em`.

[image: When I check Firebug.]

Is this a known issue with a resolution? This is a website that is going to be being used in a production environment fairly soon, and I can't predict when the glitch might strike!

Comment: Does this happen only to you locally, or also on other Macs which never had previous versions of the stylesheet loaded? Anyway, I don't have a solution, but if the site goes live soon and you can't find it and you're desperate, you could add some javascript to the onload handler which checks if the font size is 1px and if so, set it to 14px or something.

Answer (score 1):

Em is relative to the font size of its direct or nearest parent, Rem is only relative to the html (root) font-size.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to set font size of html in ems, because then it will be relative to browser font size. Usually browser font size is 16px but it may defer. Later on you can use rems which will be relative to root value html.

Comment: Will that help mitigate the issue?

Comment: In combination with some CSS reset file, to solve browser  inconsistencies, and with proper using ems and rems values  it should be fine, expect if there is some know bug regarding Mozilla on Mac...